# How to use GnomeKeyring with removable medium?

Tags: security, gnome, gnome3, removable-storage, gnome-keyring

According to the [GnomeKeyring Goal wiki pages](https://wiki.gnome.org/GnomeKeyring/Goals), the feature [Storing Keyrings on Removable Disks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/Removable) has already been implemented since 2.31, which happened in 2013.

There is no further details or documentation on the feature anywhere I can find. So how exactly can I use the feature? How do I use my keys on CD / USB Drive or other removable medium?

Thanks!